# The errors that occur in the Google Chrome extension which has Sentry installed, don't show on the Sentry site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sentry

As a Google Chrome extension developer, I want to use Sentry as an error tracking to track the errors coming from users who use the extension. I found beneficial documentation here https://www.mikesallese.me/blog/installing-sentry-in-chrome-extension/. So I already did the steps provided in the link, but the errors happening in the extension, which I can see from the console, don't get captured in Sentry. Accordingly, if anyone who has Sentry experience with Google chrome extension could help me with this, it would be very nice.

Comment: That's my blog you referenced.  Would love to help out.  What's the issue you're seeing?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Errors are coming to console but they are not going to sentry.